# Shuffle function is not being implemented correctly in Swift 1.2

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, shuffle, swift-playground

I have a function, which is used to shuffle an array. This function is working fine in playground but when I am trying to implement it on my project I am having an error.

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import Darwin

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func shuffle<C: MutableCollectionType where C.Index.Distance == Int>(var list: C) -> C {
        var n = count(list)
        if n == 0 { return list }
        let oneBeforeEnd = advance(list.startIndex, n.predecessor())
        for i in list.startIndex..<oneBeforeEnd {
            let ran = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(n--)))
            let j = advance(i,ran)
            swap(&list[i], &list[j])
        }
        return list
    }

    var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

    shuffle(numbers)


}
```

The error is occurring when I am calling  `shuffle()` saying `expected declaration`. Can anyone tell me where should I add the function or should I do something to implement correctly this code.

Comment: You need to declare the function inside some class

Comment: it is like that actually. I am updating the code but it dose not work

Comment: Now your call of `shuffle` needs to be itself inside another method, e.g. inside `viewDidLoad`

Comment: perfect. If u want to add answer the question so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move the call of `shuffle` to the body of any method. For example `viewDidLoad`. You either have to move the declaration and definition of the `numbers` to there too - or at least move it to the start of the class declaration:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] // either have the var decl here

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] // or here
        shuffle(numbers)
    }

    ...

    func shuffle<C: MutableCollectionType where C.Index.Distance == Int>(var list: C) -> C {
        ...
    }
}
```